# parallel c# number of used cores

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing

Is it possible to determine number of maximum cores used in Parallel.For ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to limit the CPU usage in parallel programming, [ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism.aspx) is a good idea.

Comment: Ok so how can I know how many cores machine on which Im running app has ?

Comment: @gruber: You need [Environment.ProcessorCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.processorcount.aspx)